# Unable to parse ajax success method data properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am working at Codeigniter and trying to parse ajax success method data using `jQuery.parseJSON`but it is unable to parse data properly. I fill the PHP Array through loop and return this array to ajax response.This is the result data.

```
[
 [
   {
    "PP_id":"1",
    "PP_purchase":"1",
    "PP_imei":"12112",
    "PP_purchasePrice":"100",
    "PP_salePrice":"200",
    "PP_color":"red",
    "PP_memory":"8",
    "PP_memoryUnit":"MB",
    "PP_sim":"Dual",
    "PP_modifiedBy":null,
    "PP_saleStatus":"1",
    "PP_saleId":"1",
    "User_id":"1",
    "deleted":"0"
  }
 ],
 [
  {
    "PP_id":"2",
    "PP_purchase":"2",
    "PP_imei":"12112",
    "PP_purchasePrice":"100",
    "PP_salePrice":"200",
    "PP_color":"red",
    "PP_memory":"8",
    "PP_memoryUnit":"GB",
    "PP_sim":"Single",
    "PP_modifiedBy":null,
    "PP_saleStatus":"0",
    "PP_saleId":"0",
    "User_id":"1",
    "deleted":"0"
   },
   {
     "PP_id":"3",
     "PP_purchase":"2",
     "PP_imei":"78878",
     "PP_purchasePrice":"200",
     "PP_salePrice":"300",
     "PP_color":"blue",
     "PP_memory":"4",
     "PP_memoryUnit":"MB",
     "PP_sim":"Dual",
     "PP_modifiedBy":null,
     "PP_saleStatus":"1",
     "PP_saleId":"1",
     "User_id":"1",
     "deleted":"0"
   }
 ]
]
```

How to parse this type of data in ajax.
This is what I want to have.

```
[
   {
    "PP_id":"1",
    "PP_purchase":"1",
    "PP_imei":"12112",
    "PP_purchasePrice":"100",
    "PP_salePrice":"200",
    "PP_color":"red",
    "PP_memory":"8",
    "PP_memoryUnit":"MB",
    "PP_sim":"Dual",
    "PP_modifiedBy":null,
    "PP_saleStatus":"1",
    "PP_saleId":"1",
    "User_id":"1",
    "deleted":"0"
  },
  {
    "PP_id":"2",
    "PP_purchase":"2",
    "PP_imei":"12112",
    "PP_purchasePrice":"100",
    "PP_salePrice":"200",
    "PP_color":"red",
    "PP_memory":"8",
    "PP_memoryUnit":"GB",
    "PP_sim":"Single",
    "PP_modifiedBy":null,
    "PP_saleStatus":"0",
    "PP_saleId":"0",
    "User_id":"1",
    "deleted":"0"
   },
   {
     "PP_id":"3",
     "PP_purchase":"2",
     "PP_imei":"78878",
     "PP_purchasePrice":"200",
     "PP_salePrice":"300",
     "PP_color":"blue",
     "PP_memory":"4",
     "PP_memoryUnit":"MB",
     "PP_sim":"Dual",
     "PP_modifiedBy":null,
     "PP_saleStatus":"1",
     "PP_saleId":"1",
     "User_id":"1",
     "deleted":"0"
   }
 ]
```

This is my PHP function in controller to load data.

```
public function myControllerMethod()
    {
        $detail = array();
        $product_id = $this->input->post('product_id');
        $sale_id = $this->input->post('sale_id');
        $purchases=$this->purchase_model->modelFunction($product_id);
        $detail=array();
        foreach($purchases as $purchase)
        {
            $detail[] = $this->my_model->mymethod($purchase->$sale_id);
        }
        echo json_encode($detail);
    }
```

parsing works fine if PHP loop execute once In the controller.
how can I do this.

Comment: its unclear what you're trying to achieve here. Please edit the question and provide more spesific case

Comment: first check that myControllerMethod() is return some thing...and please share your view code

Comment: you marked this question javascript ... in JS ... `newData = [].concat(...oldData)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$product_id = $this->input->post('product_id');
    $sale_id = $this->input->post('sale_id');
    $purchases=$this->purchase_model->modelFunction($product_id);
    $detail=array();
    foreach($purchases as $purchase)
    {
        $detail[] = $this->my_model->mymethod($purchase->$sale_id);
    }
    $test_arrey = [];
    foreach ($detail as $key => $value) {
       foreach ($value as $key => $some) {
          $test_arrey[] = $some;
       }
   }
   echo json_encode($test_arrey);
}
```

Hope this code work....